# angular date filter no effects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular, angularjs-scope

I have date in this format

```
2016-05-22 08:00:00
```

I am trying to apply a filter like this

```
<td>{{ event._source.event_date | date :  "dd.MM.y"}}</td>
```

but this does notthing.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Angular 1:**

Add following function to your scope to get Date object from your string. First it converts your string with date to format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` (adding 'T' between `YYYY-MM-DD` and `HH:MM:SS`).

```
 $scope.isoDate = function(dateString) {
   return new Date(dateString.split(' ').join('T'));
 };
```

Now you can use it:

```
{{ isoDate(event._source.event_date) |  date :  "dd.MM.y" }}
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29mbb0qk)

Answer (score 2):

The date pipe requires the value of type `Date`. A value of string is currently not supported (but work-in-progress).

You can convert the date using `new Date('2016-05-22 08:0:00')` (not checked if the format is correct and accepted though)

Comment: 2.0.0-rc.2 (2016-06-15) "common: DatePipe supports ISO string (abc266f), closes #7794" https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md